# Validating URLs with non traditional characters

Tags: urlencode, filter-var

I have a URL with special characters, example:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/c/ファンタシ.jpg';
```

I can't validate it with:

```
var_dump( (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) );
```

Because it isn't a valid URL according to the [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt):

> "Only alphanumerics [0-9a-zA-Z], the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),"
>   [not including the quotes - ed], and reserved characters used for
>   their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL"

And I can't do:

```
urlencode($url);
```

Because that will encode the entire string with encoded slashes, colon etc.

So how do I encode the `$url` properly so it passed the validation?